# Serialize unchecked radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms

```
<form>
    // radio group 1
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="Y">Yes
    <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="a" value="N">No
    <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="a" value="O">Don't know</br>

    // radio group 2
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="Y">Yes
    <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="b" value="N">No
    <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="b" value="O">Don't know</br>

    // text input
    <input type='text' value='something' name="txt" />
</form>
```

I have this form, i am trying to get the value of `a` as `false` if nothing is selected in radio group 1. (*same for other radio groups*) their can be any number of radio groups.

```
var str = $('form input:not([type="radio"])').serialize();
var str1 = $("form input[type='radio']").map(function () {
    return this.name + "=" + this.checked;
}).get().join("&");
if (str1 != "" && str != "") str += "&" + str1;
else str += str1;
```

Output is : `txt=something&a=false&a=false&a=false&b=false&b=false&b=false`

As you can see i am getting false for each radio in a group. But i want only `a=false` if none is selected. How can i achieve this ?

**Fiddle :**  http://jsfiddle.net/WcxwV/

**Edit :**

expected output :

`txt=something&a=false&b=false`

Comment: I don't understand your problem as it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/WcxwV/3/

Comment: i just updated my question with what i expect.

Comment: I'm not getting the goal of this, if user doesn't check any of the radio buttons you will receive just nothing.. so what the need to handle it?

Comment: Normally you'd handle this on the serverside with something as simple as `isset( $_POST['a'] )` to see if anything was checked ?

Comment: unchecked items don't get submitted to the server, and sending unchecked radio buttons makes even less sense. only one radio in any given group is supposed to be ever checked, so why send the unchecked ones?

Answer (score 1):

If you just added another hidden radio button that is checked and its value="", you problem would be solved

```
<input type="radio" name="a" value="" checked style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do `var str = $('form').serialize();` and then treat missing variables as not selected. That is the intended use. I don't see a reason to manually set it equal to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
var $radio = $('input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]',this);
$.each($radio,function(){
    if(!o.hasOwnProperty(this.name)){
        o[this.name] = '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

[code sample](http://codepen.io/tangolivesky/pen/bZxrkx)